# zf2 annotation for select element

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I'm getting a bit confused with zf2 annotations, I created a few elements based on [this tutorial](http://mwop.net/blog/2012-07-02-zf2-beta5-forms.html):

```php
/**
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"text" })
 * @Annotation\Required(false)
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Cardholder's Name: *:"})
 */
protected $cardholder;
```

For simple text all is working fine but I'm stuck when try to create a select element.

If you know any tutorial or github repo please let me know.

Comment: Have you searched on your own and tried to find a solution?

Comment: I tried diferent variations but it still doesn't work 

/**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Card Type:"})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"options":{"hi":"2","hi2":"2"}})
     */
    protected $cardType;

Answer (score 8):

Problem was in view 
so to get select you need 
added example for validation and filtering

```
/**
* @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"text" })
* @Annotation\Options({"label":"Cardholder's Name: *:"})
* @Annotation\Required(false)
* @Annotation\Filters({"name":"StripTags"},{"name":"StringTrim"}}) 
* @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength","options":{"min":"1", "max":"20"}})
*/

protected $cardholder;

/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Description"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"options":{"1":"Visa","2":"Maestro"}})
 */
protected $cardType;
```

and in view

```
<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('cardholder')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php 
echo $this->formInput($form->get('cardholder'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('cardholder'));
?></dd>

<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('cardType')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php 
echo $this->formSelect($form->get('cardType'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('cardType'));
?></dd>
```

Comment: what if you going to load that master or Visa from DB?

Comment: Use a factory to create the form and then populate it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
 * @Annotation\Required(false)
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Cardholder's Name: *:", "value_options":{"1":"VISA", "2":"MASTER CARD", "3":"AMERICAN EXPRESS"}})
 */
protected $cardholder;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
     * @Annotation\Required({"required":"false" })
     * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
     * 
     *
     */
```